# A specific term used for person who studies properties of gold

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word for who studies properties of gold?

I think *goldsmith* would be inappropriate cause
goldsmith is one who works on it rather having proper theoretical knowledge about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not specific to gold, ***[mineralogist](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mineralogist)*** is a profession related to the study of gold properties:

> - The study of minerals, including their distribution, identification, and properties.

(AHD)

- *[The process mineralogy of gold: The classification of ore types](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11837-004-0092-8)*: